# How to change the name of menu item after its selected in highcharts menu items?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There are graphics data for which it was necessary to make the appearance of the plate when choosing an item. But the standard function does not support the title of the `table` in html format, although the title of the `chart` supports it normally. I did it by adding a new button to the menu, through `menuItemDefinitions` inside `exporting`, but how to overwrite its text after selection? It is necessary that, as with the standard output, it was. Changed `View data table` to `Hide data table` and vice versa. The code that i have now and the photo as i would like are given below:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var html = '<div style="display: inline-block"></div>';
html += '<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; cursor: pointer;" class="description-title" id="">';
html += '<img style="width: 20px;" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/500/info--v1.png" alt="Info">';
html += '</div>';
new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart_1',
    type: 'column',
    height: 350,
 },
 title: {
    text: html,
    useHTML: true,
 },
 xAxis: {
    categories: ['Processing.js', 'Impact.js', 'Other', 'Ease.js', 'Box2D.js', 'WebGL', 'DOM', 'CSS', 'Canvas', 'Javascript']
 },
 yAxis: {
    title: {
       text: 'Asked'
    }
 },
 series: [{
    name: 'Dev #1',
    data: [5, 10, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 40, 80, 90],
    color: '#FF0000',
    states: {
        inactive: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #2',
    data: [15, 15, 18, 40, 30, 25, 60, 60, 80, 70],
    states: {
        inactive: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #3',
    data: [1, 3, 6, 0, 50, 25, 50, 60, 30, 100]
 }],
 exporting: {
        menuItemDefinitions: {
            // Custom definition
            label: {
                onclick: function() {
                  if (this.dataTableDiv && this.dataTableDiv.style.display !== 'none') {
                    this.text = "View data table";// Assigned but not displayed in the menu
                    this.dataTableDiv.style.display = 'none';
                    this.dataTableDiv.querySelector(".highcharts-table-caption").innerHTML = html;
                  } else {
                    this.viewData();
                    this.text = "Hide data table";// Assigned but not displayed in the menu
                    this.dataTableDiv.style.display = '';
                    this.dataTableDiv.querySelector(".highcharts-table-caption").innerHTML = html;
                  }
                },

                text:"View data table",
            }
        },
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: ["viewFullscreen", "printChart", "separator", "downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "downloadPDF", "downloadSVG", "separator", "downloadCSV", "downloadXLS", 'label']
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.actions, .chart {
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="chart_1" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And the solution was easier than I thought. Just instead `this.text = "Hide data table";` should have written:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-menu-item")[8].innerHTML = "Hide/View data table";
```

What solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the text inside the button is implemented, it changes the name when you hide the table to `show table` and vice versa, when you add:

```
  exporting: {
    showTable: true,
  },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9musLgp2/